# How to concatenate pieces of text?

Tags: errors, loops, pgffor

I want to concatenate pieces of text. My attempt:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}

\def\mytext{zero}
\foreach \t in {one, two, three, four}{
    \edef\tmp{\mytext\ + \t}
    \xdef\mytext{\tmp}
}
Text: (\mytext).
\end{document}
```

But when I use cedilla with '\edef' it fails with an "illegal parameter number" error. Accented chars such as `á`, `ü` are ok.

```
\foreach \t in {one, two, three, four, caça}{...  % caça issues an error
```

The problem seems to appear regardless I use UTF-8 and the package `inputenc`.

Is there a workaround for this issue? The text will **never** be formatted (e.g., bold, italic).

Comment: You need `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`

Comment: That worked. I should know better!!! :-)